# Why is x=1 not reflexive? (or determining the properties of reflexive relations)

Tags: relations

I have a question that I got wrong in my homework and I am having trouble understanding.

It says "Determine whether the relation R on the set of all real numbers is reflexive, sym-
metric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive, where (x, y) ∈ R if and only if"

One of these are x=1.

This means the relation looks like this:

1,1   1,2    1,3   1,4

and so on. That means that X will never not be one. I determine this as reflexive because every x has a matching y, such as 1,1. However, if every Y also has to have a matching X, then I am wrong.

Is my latter guess correct? Does reflexive mean if x,y, every x must have a matching x,x or does it also apply that every y must have a y,y.

Answer (score 8):

Reflexive means that for every $t$, $(t,t)$ is in the relation. The relation $x=1$ is not reflexive as $(2,2)$ is not in the relation.

Comment: It must go both ways then. If I have a 1,2, then a 2,2 must exist as well.

Comment: @munchschair: no, for reflexive you just care about $(t,t)$.  All pairs like that must be in the relation for the relation to be reflexive.  Whether $(1,2)$ is in the relation is immaterial to whether the relation is reflexive-you can have all the extra pairs you want as long as you have the required ones.

Comment: So any number X in the relation must have a x,x pair in the relation?

Comment: @munchschair: For each $x$ in the set on which the relation is based you must have $\langle x,x\rangle$ in the relation. In your problem that set is the set of real numbers, so $R$ would be reflexive only if $\langle x,x\rangle$ were in $R$ for every real number $x$: $\langle\pi,\pi,\rangle\in R,\langle 2,2\rangle\in R,\langle\sqrt2,\sqrt2\rangle\in R$, etc.